# Breaking up Float into two Shorts

Tags: c

Okay.
I have a float array:

```
float Array[2];
```

I want to write two 2 byte short integers to the first address of this array like these two:

```
short one = 100;
short two = 200;
```

How can I line up the bytes here and write short one and short two to address Array[0]?

Thanks!

Comment: `((short*)Array)[0] = one; ((short*)Array)[1] = two;` Is there a good reason for wanting to do this?

Comment: .. or use a `union` ..

Comment: No but I want one and two stored side by side at Array[0] with no overflow into Array[1]

Comment: @Fra            Could you post an example output of what you are expecting because your statements are slightly ambiguous.

Comment: If you are trying to do some kind of type conversion, you are doing it wrong. Use functions/macros provided by a platform, or in the worst case - cast. First of all, float representation in memory is more complex than int and it's cousins, second, you have to take in account architecture specifics -- endianness, type sizes etc.

Answer (score 5):

This is dangerous. A `short` in C is guaranteed to be *at least* 16 bits so it could be larger than you think.

A `float` is probably 32 bits and you can probably limit your solution to that case. (Use a static assertion based on `sizeof(float) == 4`).

Using `int16_t` in place of `short` will be safer: that's a 16 bit signed type and has been standard since C99.

This union will be safe:

```
union 
{
    int16_t arr[2];
    float f;
};
```

The standard guarantees (i) that `arr` will be contiguous, and (ii), the address of `f` is the same as the address of `arr[0]`.

Comment: I fear there's not guarantee for floats being 32-bit either, in fact they frequently aren't in the embedded world. Unfortunately the strict aliasing rules also forbid the union trick, at least unless you go the roundabout way via a char. My suggestion would be a memcpy() coupled with a static assertion to verify the expected type sizes.

Comment: I *thought* there was a guarantee of 32 bit; but they are not necessarily IEEE. But I'll read up on the "via a char" thing you mention.

Comment: Hmm... I didn't realize these primitive types were this volatile.

Comment: @Batsheba: I fear the C standard(s) make very few guarantees about the floating-point types, just some minimum limits on the precision and range. In practice I've encountered both 64 and 24-bit floats in the wild in software floating-point libraries for C compilers on 8-bit MCUs.

Comment: You are, of course, correct. My answer asserted the size of the floating point type to be 32 bits, which is wrong.

Comment: The assertion should be `sizeof(float) == 2*sizeof(int16_t)`.  This is directly a condition of the posted `union`.  `sizeof(float) == 4` invokes other unneeded conditions